# Problem with pulling image from private hub

Tags: docker, mesosphere, dcos

I have the following problem : Trying to pull built docker image from private hub and run it as a service, but the following error appears

`Failed to launch container: Failed to run 'docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock pull r.cfcr.io/path/to/repo/': exited with status 1; stderr='Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device '`

here is the fetch[] config.json info that I am using to authenticate :

```
{
    "auths": {
        "r.cfcr.io": {
            "auth": "=auth_token="
        }
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
        "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.06.1-ce (linux)"
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve the problem?

Comment: What command do you use to pull the image?

Comment: It works when I try to pull it through command line, but it fails through Mesosphere UI

Comment: What do you mean to run it as a service?

Comment: Mesosphere UI -> Run a service -> Multi-container Pod. It fails when I try to build it in that way

Comment: The error shows that cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device.

Comment: Yes, that is why I am wondering what may be the problem - it works when I authenticate and pull the image via command line, but when I try to do it via Mesosphere UI the error above appears every time

Answer (score 0):

Probably not linked to the problem here, but some people might encounter the exact same message when trying a docker login from a Linux like terminal on Windows such as Git bash or Docker quickstart terminal or even Cygwin.

The trick here is to use `winpty docker login`

**or try to use this command**

```
docker login "${URL}" -u "${Username}" -p "${PASSWORD}"
```

Comment: The problem is it is working when I authenticate via command line. Respectively - I can pull the image and build it without any problems. It is not working via Mesosphere UI

Answer (score 0):

You must keep the config.json file at .docker directory at $MESOS_SANDBOX.
So create the archieve of .docker directory with below listing of files :

```
$ tar tvf docker-login.tar                                                                                      
drwx------ parvez/parvez     0 2019-06-12 21:45 .docker/
-rw------- parvez/parvez   177 2019-06-12 21:45 .docker/config.json
```

Fetch and extract this archive from mesos configuration.

```
"fetch": [{ 
              "uri": "https://foo.com/docker-login.tar", 
              "executable": false,
              "extract": true, 
              "cache": true 
          }],
```

It will download and extract archieve at $MESOS_SANDBOX path and docker pull should be successful.